# Perspective Transform on iOS With glOrthof & OpenGL 1.1

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I've got a relatively large OpenGL 1.1 iOS codebase that uses OGL as a 2D graphics API through:

```
glOrthof(0, framebufferWidth, 0, framebufferHeight, -1, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

All the drawing is then done in 2D, but I'd like to offer a feature of perspective drawing e.g.:

[image]

I'm really unsure how to go about it, most of the searches I've made pointed me at picking or perspective for 3D gaming not so much for 2D drawing with OpenGL 1.1 (I found some references for 2.0 but the migration seems unfeasible right now).